# php is not interpreting inpinfo on new centos install

Tags: centos, php

I just installed latest centos as a desktop version.
Then I installed php via yum and turned on httpd.
Php code is being interpreted, but phpinfo() is messed up.
I see all the html code as well as the phpinfo variables.
How do I fix?

Comment: PHP comes in many forms ( mod_php, cgi_php, fastcgi, etc) which one did you install, which one do you want.  Did you install the correct version?

Comment: yum install php

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
phpinfo() will only display correctly if you browse to it using a domain name.
I was using the server's IP and it would not display correctly.

Comment: Hmmm...this is not true. If this actually solved your problem, ok, but the root cause has, IMHO, more to do with your Web Server config